# Does setting up a company for your own improves credibility?

Tags: loans, credit, private-company

I have been working as a freelancer for quite a while now. Today, when I am trying to get a car loan, the agency asked me:

1. Are you currently employed and have regular salary? *(No)*
2. Do you have a business card? *(No)*
3. Are you running your own company? *(No)*

If I set up a new company which pays me regular salary, and then bill my customers using the company's name instead of my own, will that improve my ability to carry a loan in the eyes of credit companies?

Comment: If you are employed by an existing company, then what is the answer to question #1? If you "set up a new company which pays me regular salary", then what is the answer to question #1? If the answer to question #1 in either case is "yes", then is it likely that questions #2 and #3 will be asked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is that you are defacto running your own company no matter if you acknowledge it or not.  In the end these questions have the goal of deciding if you can and will repay the loan.  Presumably you filed taxes on your income.  These can be shown to the loan officer as proof you have the ability to repay your loan.

Running your freelancing as a business has advantages of being able to deduct normal expenses for running the business from your revenue.

I am not sure how business cards improves your credit worthiness as they can be had for $10 in about an hour.